# Is it possible to know which menus are owned by a plugin?

Tags: plugins, menus

I'm building a plugin that needs to generate a list of active plugins along with the menus that were created by each plugin. After browsing core I couldn't find anything that would associate the creation of a menu or menus to an activated plugin.

Comment: Core doesn't store data on how menus are created or what creates them. It might be possible to search all the `plugins` and `mu-plugins` files on a site for all the `wp_nav_menu` calls (for front end) and `add_menu_page` calls (for back end), but that could be a pretty resource-intensive kind of check. You would want to run it once when your plugin is activated, and then hook into plugin activation so that whenever additional plugins are activated your plugin searches the new files - though this wouldn't catch new `mu-plugins`.

Comment: I think there are a few approaches which might get you pretty close by digging through some globals and using reflection against callables. They would be fairly convoluted and rely on some assumptions, and certainly would not catch cases where menus are conditionally added  - but I think it's an interesting possibility without much hackery that may be worth exploring. Straight up hijacking hooks or rigging the menu globals with magic methods could also yield results - but I don't think either would be fit for distribution. A personal development tool, maybe - but definitely not production.

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, you can use PHP's `debug_backtrace()` function along with appropriate WordPress hooks like `wp_nav_menu`, `add_menu_page` etc. to get the file names and function names these WordPress API functions/hooks are called from.

From there, you should be able to determine which plugin is creating or modifying what menu.

However, please note that functions like `debug_backtrace()` is very resource intensive. So you shouldn't use them unless it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thanks @Fayaz. I started messing around with debug_backtrace and I  really like it and it  does what I need. When I tested it the performance and resource use wasn't really an issue because I only needed to return the first line or 2 (debug_backtrace( 1, 2 ). Unfortunately there is no core hook for the add_menu_page function. :(

Comment: Check the source CODE of `add_menu_page`. From there you'll see that you can still check the contents of the global variables `global $menu, $admin_page_hooks, $_registered_pages, $_parent_pages;` to get all the information you need. e.g. you can get plugin names from `$admin_page_hooks[ $menu_slug ]`